# Flink executes dataflow twice

Tags: apache-flink

I'm new to Flink and I work with DataSet API. After a whole bunch of processing as the last stage I need to normalize one of the values by dividing it by its maximum value. So, I have used the `.max()` operator to take the max and later I'm passing the result as constructor's argument to the MapFunction.

This works, however all the processing is performed twice. One job is executed to find max values, and later another job is executed to create final result (starting execution from the beginning)... Is there any workaround to execute whole dataflow only once?

```
  final List<Tuple6<...>> maxValues = result.max(2).collect();
  assert maxValues.size() == 1;
  result.map(new NormalizeAttributes(maxValues.get(0))).writeAsCsv(...)

@FunctionAnnotation.ForwardedFields("f0; f1; f3; f4; f5")
@FunctionAnnotation.ReadFields("f2")
private static class NormalizeAttributes implements MapFunction<Tuple6<...>, Tuple6<...>> {

    private final Tuple6<...> maxValues;

    public NormalizeAttributes(Tuple6<...> maxValues) {
        this.maxValues = maxValues;
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple6<...> map(Tuple6<...> value) throws Exception {
        value.f2 /= maxValues.f2;
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collect()` immediately triggers an execution of the program up to the dataset requested by `collect()`. If you later call `env.execute()` or `collect()` again, the program is executed second time.

Besides the side effect of execution, using `collect()` to distribute values to subsequent transformation has also the drawback that data is transferred to the client and later back into the cluster. Flink offers so-called Broadcast variables to ship a `DataSet` as a side input into another transformation.

Using Broadcast variables in your program would look as follows:

```
DataSet maxValues = result.max(2);
result
  .map(new NormAttrs()).withBroadcastSet(maxValues, "maxValues")
  .writeAsCsv(...);
```

The `NormAttrs` function would look like this:

```
private static class NormAttr extends RichMapFunction<Tuple6<...>, Tuple6<...>> {

  private Tuple6<...> maxValues;

  @Override
  public void open(Configuration config) {
    maxValues = (Tuple6<...>)getRuntimeContext().getBroadcastVariable("maxValues").get(1);
  }

  @Override
  public PredictedLink map(Tuple6<...> value) throws Exception {
    value.f2 /= maxValues.f2;
    return value;
  }
}
```

You can find more information about Broadcast variables in the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/batch/index.html#broadcast-variables).